# Remote repository not found on changed url GitHub

Tags: git, github

I changed my remote repository location using git command to new location.

```
git remote set-url origin https://git.companyname.com/domain/mycode.git
```

but if I browse new location(https://git.companyname.com/domain/mycode) it gives '404 Page not found' and repository is still available at old location. Do you have idea why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you believe that changing the remote repository that your local repo points to will move the remote.  That's not the case.  When you made that change, you merely started pointing to an invalid remote repo - one that doesn't exist.  That's why you get the 404.

You would have to ensure that the new remote URL is valid first, then point your local repo to use it as a remote, then push your content to it.

**Update:** If you merely need a remote in a new location, you don't really need to "move" anything. Merely create the new remote (Github.com, Bitbucket.com, local Gitlabs install, etc) and then define it using the "remote set-url origin" command in your question, and to a git push to it.

The key here is that Git is distributed.  You can have as many remotes as you like - there is no sense of one, single canonical repository like there is in Subversion, for example.

Comment: I'm new to git, do you know how to move my remote repository to a new location? can it be done using command line only?

Comment: @mmmathur I updated the answer with more detail that might make it more clear to you.